# In DDD Aggregate + Event Sourcing, do Events happen before or after state changes?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, aggregate

Part of the Aggregate + Event Sourcing (A+ES) methodology feels
uncomfortable.
Why does it feel uncomfortable? (As I've read from other questions and the book itself, it's a new-ish way of thinking, and the literature may not be great.)

I think part of it is the separation between state ownership, and
state transition source.

The Domain Model has an Aggregate. Clients can affect changes in the
Aggregate by Application Services. Application Services are the direct
client of the Domain Model. Application Services call methods on the
Aggregate. The Aggregate can publish Domain Events. The Aggregate
decides if a Domain Event gets published, and if so, which Domain Event
gets published. Typically, the Event reflects some change to the state
of the Aggregate; or, the Event reflects something that has happened.
Some change has occurred, and an Event followed that occurence. The
change happened-before the Event. The Event happened-after the change.

With A+ES, we reconstitute the state of an Aggregate from the Events
that have occurred. When a new Aggregate instance is created, there are
no Events to reconstitute the state from, so the Aggregate is a blank
slate. When the Aggregate is commanded to do something by an Application
Service, some change happens, and an Event is published that records
that change. Later, when we want to use that Aggregate instance again,
we retrieve the Event Stream for that Aggregate instance, and feed the
Events into it.

This I think is the part that makes me feel uncomfortable. The Aggregate
takes commands from Application Services, performs some action that
results in a state change, and publishes an Event that a change has
occurred. With A+ES, the Aggregate must also take Events that it had
published previously, and handle them accordingly. It has to react to
the commands that generate Events, and now also has to react to the
Events that it generated previously.

The example code in IDDD (Implementing Domain Driven Design) encapsulates a separate State object for the
Aggregate. The State object is then the one that is responsible for
mutating the state based on Events. In this example, the Aggregate
receives the Events by means of its constructor, but then completely
hands off the Events to a State object created in the constructor. This
is called out as separating the behavior and the state into two
different classes, with the behavior class (the Aggregate) referencing
the state class to make decisions, and only permitting the state class
to be modified via Events. The state can be queried directly from the
Aggregate (eg. `state.Name` or `state.Id`), but it cannot be changed
directly by the Aggregate (there are no setter methods available to
support `state.Name = "...";` or `state.SetName(...);`). The only way to
change anything about the State, is to give the State an Event, and let
the State determine what happens with that Event. Here, it seems
that the Event comes before the change. Instead of a state change
triggering an Event, the Event triggers the state change. The command
generates an Event, and later, the Event becomes a command. To me, it
feels like an unfamiliar temporal decoupling, and an inversion of
control. It almost feels like some sort of inverted invariant
enforcement. Instead of the Aggregate making some change to the
state, ensuring the invariant is enforced, and publishing an Event that
the change was made (and implicitly, that the change satisfied the
invariant), the Aggregate instead tells its state "perform whatever
actions necessary to make this true/enforce this invariant".

A (maybe not great) example might be the difference between

```
void LockAccount() {
    AccountLocked = true;// invariant enforced here
    var event = AccountLocked(...);
    PublishEvent(event);
}
```

and

```
void LockAccount() {
    var event = AccountLocked(...);
    state.Mutate(event);// "perform whatever actions necessary for the
                        // 'AccountLocked' invariant to be enforced."
    PublishEvent(event);
}
```

Is there some fundamental concept that I've missed that is making this
feel uncomfortable, or is my understanding correct, and the
uncomfortable feeling I get is simply unfamiliarity with this design
paradigm?

**EDIT**: To explain from the comments, nothing is inherently wrong about the second code example. It makes sense mechanically. Part of the uncomfortable feeling comes from the sequence of events. If we only had the Aggregate class, and it managed behavior and state, then it would be weird if we published an Event before the appropriate state change had occurred. I would expect the state to be changed (flags set, values changed, objects replaced, etc) before an Event reflecting that state change was created.

With A+ES, the Event is created before the necessary state changes (flags set, values changed, objects replaced, etc) have occurred in the object. In fact, the Event is entirely what drives the state changes.

I think I may have found a way to reconcile this though. It seems like Events immediately follow "decision points". A decision point seems like a point in time, or code, that something has been undeniably decided.

Let's say we had an Aggregate, that had one method, and calling that method could result in two different Events.

```
void DoSomething() {
    if (state.SomethingIsTrue) {
        var trueEvent = TrueEvent(...);
        state.Mutate(trueEvent);
    }
    else {
        var falseEvent = FalseEvent(...);
        state.Mutate(falseEvent);
    }
}
```

In this code block, we have two decision points, nicely corresponding to the if and else blocks. If something is true, we have decided what we're going to do next. If something is false, we also have decided what we're going to do next. In both cases, an Event is published after the decision point has been reached.

If we apply this to the LockAccount examples above

```
void LockAccount() {
    // decision to lock the account happened before now
    AccountLocked = true;// state is changed to reflect the decision
    var event = AccountLocked(...);// event reflects that a decision has been made
    ...
}

void LockAccount() {
    // decision to lock the account happened before now
    var event = AccountLocked(...);// event reflects that a decision has been made
    state.Mutate(event);// state is changed to reflect the decision
    ...
}
```

Looking at it this way, it's not the Event that drives the change, nor is it the Aggregate that drives the change, but it's the *decision* that drives the change. Regardless of which comes first, changing state and sending event, or sending event to change state, both happen only after a specific decision has been made. The Event then doesn't reflect that the state has been changed, but that a decision has been made.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. With this approach you describe your aggregate mutations with events, for me is perfect. With this approach you restrict the possible mutations in your domain so you have more control of them. For you what is the issue with the second example?

Comment: And this is a question, why you say that accountLocked = true; is an invariant?

Comment: @LeonardoMangano I suppose it isn't an invariant, but rather an effect, which is what lead me to think about it as more closely tied to an Event. To me, there's no inherent problem with the second example. I guess it's more about the driving factors. To me, it's more about the time relationship between the Event being created, and the state change causing that Event. Without having a separate State class, the state would be inside the Aggregate class. When the Aggregate is told to do something, by calling one of its methods, it does something. For me there's a natural tendency for Events to...

Comment: ... represent things that already happened. Without a separate State class, it seems weird if we publish the event without making the appropriate changes to the Aggregate, which is why the second example feels so strange. It feels like we're saying something happened (the account was locked) before the aggregate reflects that fact (Event is created before Locked flag is set to true). I may have thought of a way to reconcile this in my head, by determining the "decision point" of an Event. I'll see if I can find a good way to explain it in the question.

Comment: I think your last update is very clear, the event happened when you decided to create it based in a command, after some validations and based in some conditionals. After that  event was created (happened) you have lot of reactions like changing the aggregate in memory, then in the DB and then publishing the event. I think this is a good way to think about this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Looking at it this way, it's not the Event that drives the change, nor
> is it the Aggregate that drives the change, but it's the decision that
> drives the change.

Well, of course; this is what we refer to as application logic and business logic. That's what drives the change. Some of the decisions will be made in the application layer, some within the domain services, some in the methods of the aggregate, depending on how you separated the different responsibilities. Once you have your decisions sorted out, you make a state change.

However, I think what's tripping you up is a misconception about what it *means* to make state changes in an event sourcing scenario:

```
void LockAccount() {
    // decision to lock the account happened before now --> THIS IS FINE
    // You can make further decisions here if necessary

    // PROBLEM: The idea is NOT to do this two-step thing. 
    // Managing the state change is NOT a responsibility of this method/class.
    //
    AccountLocked = true; // state is changed to reflect the decision
    state.Mutate(new AccountLocked(...)); // event reflects that a decision has been made
    ...
}
```

This piece of code is an expression of what you've wrote earlier:

> Some change has occurred, and an Event followed that occurence.

But the event doesn't *follow* a change, the event *is* the change.

The whole point is that state changes are, on a high level, represented exclusively through events. En event is "something that happened" in the sense that it's not a command or a request. It's not even a notification about something else that the aggregate did. Conceptually the event stream is the source of truth, the event stream *is* the state; *as soon as you commit an event* the state has changed - that's the idea. State changes are *expressed as events*; an event is an immutable record of a change by virtue of being a direct representation of that change (it's not a log of something else you've done).

Of course, to work with the aggregate, you reduce the event stream to a single in-memory state object (you "replay" past events), but this state object is internal to the aggregate; in-memory state changes are *encapsulated*. Whether or not you have a separate State class, the Mutate method is internal to the aggregate (it's not visible to any client code), and the in-memory state itself is encapsulated behind that method. So even within the aggregate, even if it's all a single class, when changing the state, you have to act as if you don't have direct access to state variables; the only way to effect state change is to call Mutate. But that requires documentation, and a deeper understanding of the design, and developer discipline. You can instead bake this into your design by separating out the state into a distinct class, and having the Mutate method be your only "window" to state mutation. So what you get is:

```
// In Account
public void LockAccount() {
    // do some logic, if any
    
    // effect the change:
    // no other way to mutate state, all the setters are private
    this.state.Mutate(new AccountLocked(...));  
}

// In AccountState
private Mutate(IEvent event) {

   // dispatch based on event, change internal state...

    this.Changes.Add(event);      // track uncommited changes
}
```

So the `state` object is not just some helper object that sends out events - the `state` is where the in-memory state lives. There's no separate state data in the Account instance. The event stream is the source of truth, the in-memory state is your "working area".

If your business logic is organized around a lot of getters, then this separation might result in some boilerplate, but if you mostly follow the Tell-Don't-Ask principle (in other words, if you are writing OO code, and not procedural code using objects), than you won't have a lot of pass-through getters.

P.S. Just for clarity, note that the word "aggregate" in DDD doesn't mean an aggregate of events; it's an aggregate of collaborating objects (including the case where the "aggregate" is only a single object), encapsulated behind an aggregate root (AR) - a particular object that provides the interface to the whole aggregate. So the aggregate here is { Account(AR) + AccountState }, with account state being internal to the aggregate.

Comment: What a great answer to a great question!

Answer (score 2):

When and how events behave in event sourced systems depends on the context.

For **event sourced aggregates** themselves, the events happen:

- **after** business rule validations,
- **before** applying the event onto the aggregate itself.

The apply function itself modifies the aggregate's data, taking information from the recorded event and applying it on the record. The reason for this is that with event sourcing you need to reconstruct an aggregate from events, which is usually a method as simple as this:

```
class EventSourcedAggregate {

    // some state

    public static EventSourceAggregate fromEvents(Collection<Event> events) {
        foreach (events as event) {
            this.apply(event);
        }
    }
}
```

So if you have an aggregate which can be locked:

```
class Door {

    private UUID uuid;
    private boolean locked = false;

    private Collection<Event> recordedEvents = new List();

    public void lock() {
        if (locked) {
            return;
        }

        this.recordAndApply(new DoorLockedEvent(this.uuid));
    }

    private void applyDoorLockedEvent(DoorLockedEvent event) {
        this.locked = true;
    }

    private void recordAndApply(Event event) {
        this.recordedEvents.add(event);

        this.apply(event);
    }

    private void apply(Event event) {
        if (event is DoorLockedEvent) {
            this.applyDoorLockedEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

you don't want to change the aggregate's state in the `lock` method, because the method would never be called during aggregate's reconstruction.

And you also don't want the apply methods to contain any business logic, because some changes to your system since the time an event has been originally recorded could forbid the application of the event, which shouldn't be happening. Once an event has been recorded (and therefore passed the business rule constraints present at the time of the event creation), you should pretty much always be able to apply the event back onto the aggregate.

For **other parts of the system**, the events happen after the aggregate has been persisted (i.e. both after recording the event on the aggregate, as well as applying the changes to said aggregate using an apply method). Of course, for this you need some sort of infrastructure, which read the `recordedEvents` from the persisted aggregate and publishes them, so that other modules may listen to them.